# MySQL JSON data type update with delete

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and JSON data type and PHP.

First I update my data.

```
UPDATE car SET attributes = JSON_SET(`attributes`'$.A','Audi','$.B','BMW','$.C','Cadillac')
```

The result is this which is correct.

```
{
"A": "Audi",
"B": "BMW",
"C": "Cadillac"
}
```

Then I try to update "B" with "". Then my data looks like this.

```
{
"A": "Audi",
"B": "",
"C": "Cadillac"
}
```

But I want it to look like this. (I want to remove "B" if it's empty).

```
{
"A": "Audi",
"C": "Cadillac"
}
```

How do I do this the correct way?

Comment: I would suggest you use `json_encode();` and `json_decode();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

```
UPDATE `car` SET `attributes` = JSON_REMOVE(`attributes`, '$.B');
```